# On the theorem that allows us to manipulate conditional densities.

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions, density-function

Given a random vector $(X,Y) \in AC$ with density $\gamma_{(X,Y)}(x,y) $ we set

$$\gamma_{(X|Y)}(x,y) := \frac{ \gamma_{(X,Y)}(x,y)  }{ \gamma_{Y}(y)} \mathbb{1}_{(\gamma_Y(y) > 0)} (y), \qquad  (x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^n \times \mathbb{R}   $$

And we call

$$\mu_{X|Y}(H,y) := \int_H \gamma_{(X|Y)}(x,y) \,dx, \qquad H \in B_d, y \in R
$$

A regular version of the conditional distribution of $X$ given $Y$.

In this theoretical probabilistic context could someone tell me which **theorem** allows us to claim results on the conditional **densities** such as that

$$\gamma_{(X+aY|Y)}(x,y) = \gamma_{(X|Y)}(x - ay,y) $$

and that $$\gamma_{(X,Y)}(x,y) =  \gamma_{(X-Y, Y)}(x-y,y)$$

Comment: The order of your definitions is inverted in the probability theory context. Roguhly, we begin by defining the conditional measure (by way of defining conditional expectation), and then define the density (as the Radon-Nikodym derivative of the conditional measure wrt the Lebesgue measure, but that's not too important). The statements then follow from the usual substitution rules in integration, which you can likely find proofs of.

Comment: @stochasticboy321 could you give me a reference on which to study the approach you just explained?

Comment: There are many standard texts, for instance Billingsley's Probability and Measure or Dudley's Probability and Real Analysis. Note that these are in-depth treatments that are usually studied over a year in grad school, so this might be too much depending on your background &co. In particular, consult the chapters on conditional expectation.